# Angular js : Open div on clicking panel and close itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I Have a row ,  panel and a div which is closed on load.

when I click on panel then the div should get appear and  row as well as panel should get disappear and when i click on **X** then panel and row should get appear.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margin_text">
    <div class=" font-thin pull-left margin_top_4 padding_left_20">
      <span class="font_size_17 ">Discussion Forum</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-header" ng-click="open_div=true">Click me</div>
</div>


<div ng-show="open_div">
  Div Opened <span>X</span>
</div>
```

when I click on **Click me** then div should open and discussion forum row and panel should get disappear. and when I click on **X** then that div should get closed and panel and row should appear.

Comment: Why can't you do the same as you did like `ng-click="open_div=true"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same `open_div` for hiding.

As well as, you can use [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directive for hiding.

```html
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-show="!open_div" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margin_text">
      <div class=" font-thin pull-left margin_top_4 padding_left_20">
        <span class="font_size_17 ">Discussion Forum</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div ng-show="!open_div" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-header" ng-click="open_div=true">Click me</div>
  </div>


  <div ng-show="open_div">
    Div Opened <span ng-click="open_div=false">X</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution. But it helps.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-header" ng-click="open_div= true" ng-init="open_div=false">Click me</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="open_div">Div Opened <span ng-click="open_div= false">X</span>
```